# A question on ultrapower

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, ultrafilters, ultrapowers

Suppose $\kappa_0$ is a measurable cardinal and $\mu_0$ is a normal measure on $\kappa_0$. $M_1$ is the transitive collapse of $Ult(V,\mu_0)$, $j_{0,1}:V\rightarrow{M_1}$ is the elementary embedding induced by the ultrapower. In $M_1$, $\kappa_1=j_{0,1}(\kappa_0)$ is a measurable cardinal and $\mu_1$ is a normal measure on $\kappa_1$ in $M_1$ such that $\mu_1$ is not in the range of $j_{0,1}$. $M_2$ is the transitive collapse of $Ult(M_1,\mu_1)$, $j_{1,2}:M_1\rightarrow{M_2}$ is the elementary embedding induced by the ultrapower. $j_{0,2}=j_{1,2}\circ{j_{0,1}}$.

Is it true that: ``Suppose $N$ is an inner model, $i:V\rightarrow{N}$ and $k:N\rightarrow{M_2}$ are elementary embeddings such that $k\circ{i}=j_{0,2}$. Then $k''N=j_{0,2}''V$ or $k''N=j_{1,2}''M_1$ or $k''N=M_2$''?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an excellent and interesting question! You are asking whether the 2-step iteration of a normal measure μ on a measurable cardinal κ is uniquely factored by the steps of the iteration itself.

The answer is **Yes**.

Let me denote κ<sub>0</sub> just by κ and j<sub>02</sub> by j. Since
μ<sub>1</sub> is a measure in M<sub>1</sub>, it has the
form j<sub>01</sub>(m)(κ), where m =
(ν<sub>α</sub> | α < κ). Since you
have said that μ<sub>1</sub> is not in
ran(j<sub>01</sub>), we may choose the
ν<sub>α</sub> to be all different, and different
from μ<sub>0</sub>. In this case, there is a partition
of κ as the disjoint union of X<sub>α</sub>,
with X<sub>α</sub> in ν<sub>α</sub> and none
in μ<sub>0</sub>. Let x = (X<sub>α</sub> | α
< κ). Note that κ is not in
j<sub>01</sub>(X<sub>α</sub>) for any α <
κ, and similarly κ<sub>1</sub> is not in
j(X<sub>α</sub>). But κ is in
j<sub>01</sub>(x)(β) for some β <
κ<sub>1</sub>, since this is a partition of
κ<sub>1</sub>. Apply j<sub>12</sub> to conclude that
κ<sub>1</sub> is in j(x)(β) for this β.
Thus, there is some β in the interval [κ,
κ<sub>1</sub>) having the form β =
j(f)(κ<sub>1</sub>) for the function f that picks the
index. From this, it follows from normality of
μ<sub>0</sub> that we can write κ =
j(g)(κ<sub>1</sub>) for some function g, since any
β < κ<sub>1</sub> generates κ via
j<sub>01</sub>. In my favored terminology, the seed
κ<sub>1</sub> generates κ via j and in fact
generates all β in [κ,κ<sub>1</sub>) via
j.

Similarly, suppose that δ is in the interval
[κ<sub>1</sub>,j(κ)). We know δ =
j<sub>12</sub>(f)(κ<sub>1</sub>) for some function f
on κ<sub>1</sub> in M<sub>1</sub>. We also know f =
j<sub>01</sub>(F)(κ) for some F in V. Thus, δ =
j(F)(κ, κ<sub>1</sub>). In Y, let
(α,β) be the smallest pair with δ =
j(F)(α,β). It cannot be that both are below
κ<sub>1</sub>, since this would be inside
ran(j<sub>12</sub>) and so the least pair must have β
= κ<sub>1</sub>. Thus, δ generates
κ<sub>1</sub>, which we already observed generates
κ.

To summarize, every ordinal in the interval
[κ<sub>1</sub>,j(κ)) generates
κ<sub>1</sub>, which generates all the ordinals
β in [κ,κ<sub>1</sub>), any of which
generate κ and all the other such β.

This is enough to answer your question. The k " N in your
question is just an arbitrary elementary substructure of
M<sub>2</sub> containing ran(j), so suppose we have Y
elementary in M<sub>2</sub> and ran(j) subset Y. The case Y
= ran(j) is one of your cases. Otherwise, Y has something
not in ran(j). Every object in M<sub>2</sub> has form
j(h)(κ,κ<sub>1</sub>) for some function h, so
by looking at the smallest pair of ordinals to generate a
given object with j(h), we see that there must be ordinals
below j(κ) in Y. If Y contains any ordinal δ in
the interval [κ<sub>1</sub>,j(κ)), then it will
contain both κ and κ<sub>1</sub>, since we
observed that any such δ generates these ordinals. In
this case, Y = M<sub>2</sub>, since those two ordinals
generate everything. So we assume that Y contains no such
δ. In this last case, Y must contain some ordinal
β in the interval [κ,κ<sub>1</sub>). Since
any such β generates κ, Y contains all such
ordinals. It follows that ran(j<sub>12</sub>) subset Y and
in fact = Y, since if Y contained anything more it would
have to have an additional ordinal δ in
[κ<sub>1</sub>,j(κ)).

So we've seen that your three cases are the only
possibilities. And like your previous question, there is no
need to assume that Y or N is somehow internally definable.

By the way, this was a problem that I had solved many years
ago for my dissertation, although perhaps other people had
also thought about it. I was interested in understanding
which pairs of ordinals (α,β) generate product
measures via an embedding j, and this question is very much
related to that.

(Click the edit history to see my previous answer, which was just about the case when μ<sub>1</sub> is in the range of j<sub>01</sub>, a case for which the answer is no.)

Comment: I am the student exchange you with email, you introduce me to go here, so I register this new name.
In my question, I require $\mu_1$ is not in the range of $j_{0,1}$, i.e. the second step of the iterated ultrapower is done by a normal measure not in $j_{0,1}''V$. For example, suppose $\kappa$ has $\kappa$ many normal measures <U_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa>, the first step of the iterated ultrapower I use $U_0$, and the second step of the iteration, I use the \kappa-th measure in the sequence j_{0,1}(<U_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa>) .


Comment: 
So the model-theoretic fact you said in your answer may not make sense in this case, since $\mu_1$ is not a normal measure in $V$. How to deal with this case?

Comment: Welcome to MO! Ah, I read your question more carefully now. You are right: my answer applies to the case where mu_1 IS in the range of j_01, for then mu_1=j_01(nu), and in this case, j02 is precisely the ultrapower by mu_0 x nu, since every object in M_2 would be j02(f)(kappa_0,kappa_1), and you map this to [f]_{mu_0xnu} for an isomorphism. For your case, where mu_1 is NOT in the range of j_01, then I believe the answer is Yes, but this is more complicated, and I will post an answer later. 

Comment: I have posted a revised answer, for the case mu_1 not in ran(j_01). Here, the answer is affirmative.